# Two stage sampling

Tags: r, simulation, sampling

I've got a population stratified by provinces (10 provinces) and I need to sample (using SRSWOR) 5 smaller areas in each province. Then, I'll have to select 1000 units per small area using SRS without replacement. 
Do you know a quick solution to this in R?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: `sample` offers sampling without replacement by default.

Comment: As @sebastian-c suggested, you can use `sample`. If you want any more advice than that, you can provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of your data and an expected output.